# Картинка слайдера не хочет высвечиваться в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Снизу код, я новичок и я не знаю как менее криво его сделать

```js
let slidCounter = 1;
let slid1 = document.getElementById('slid1')
let slid2 = document.getElementById('slid2')

slid1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  slidCounter = slidCounter + 1;
  if (slidCounter == 7) {
    slidCounter = 0;
  }
  switch (slidCounter) {
    case 0:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/grigory.jpg')";
      break;
    case 1:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/boris.jpg')";
      break;
    case 2:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/ksenia.jpg')";
      break;
    case 3:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/maksim.jpg')";
      break;
    case 4:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/pavel.jpg')";
      break;
    case 5:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/putin.jpg')";
      break;
    case 6:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/sergey.jpg')";
      break;
    case 7:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/vlad.jpg')";
      break;
  }
  console.log(slidCounter)
});

document.getElementById("slid2").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  slidCounter = slidCounter - 1;
  if (slidCounter == -1) {
    slidCounter = 6;
  }
  switch (slidCounter) {
    case 0:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url(pics/grigory.jpg')";
      break;
    case 1:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/boris.jpg')";
      break;
    case 2:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/ksenia.jpg')";
      break;
    case 3:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/maksim.jpg')";
      break;
    case 4:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/pavel.jpg')";
      break;
    case 5:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/putin.jpg')";
    case 6:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/sergey.jpg')";
      break;
    case 6:
      slidPic.style.backgroundImage = "url('pics/vlad.jpg')";
      break;
  }
  console.log(slidCounter)
});
```

```css
#slidPic {
  background-image: url(pics/grigory.jpg);
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <button id="slid1">Назад</button>
  <div id="slidPic">
  </div>
  <button id="slid2">Вперед</button>
</div>
```

Никаких ошибок не высвечивает, кнопки вполне работают, но картинка даже при просто загрузке страницы не показывается, при нажатии кнопок тоже. Еще если возможно дайте ссылки где можно узнать как делать анимации для слайдера, но не обязательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размеры `div#slidPic` = 0x0 => картинку не видно. Укажите ширину и высоту в явном виде, например так:

```
#slidPic {
  height: 80vh;
  max-height: 30rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У Вашего `<div id="slidPic">` нулевые ширина и высота.

Comment: css часть мне написал учитель, я её даже сначала не смотрел... Спасибо

Comment: @КурносовПавел Пожалуйста. Успехов.